# How to disable or enable href links and change the contents of it?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, debugging

I have a bug to fix in my code

```js
  if (!creatorUrl) {
        creatorUrl = '#';
      }
```

Basically what the above code does is, it checks if the creator has a URL to which I can redirect the user, otherwise I don't want to do anything.

```html
  <p class="vocab paragraph inherit-colored info__content info__content-creator">
                <a href="creator_url">Creator Name</a>
              </p>
```

This is the tag which I am modifying. I want the expected behaviour to be like, when the creatorUrl doesn't exist,the Link shouldn't show up at all and the creator name should be a plain text.How can I do this ?

Comment: If you want to set the url like this inside the html, you have to start over. Post all the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side, it would be an obvious place to not show a link

***EJS***

```
<p class="vocab paragraph inherit-colored info__content info__content-creator">
  <% if (creatorUrl) { %>
    <a href="<%= creatorUrl %>">Creator Name</a>
  <% } else { %>
    Creator Name
  <% } %>
</p>
```

On the client side you can do this to replace empty links with their textContent

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".info__content-creator a[href^='#']")].forEach(lnk => lnk.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(lnk.textContent), lnk));
})
```

```html
<p class="vocab paragraph inherit-colored info__content info__content-creator">
  <a href="#">Creator Name</a>
</p>

<p class="vocab paragraph inherit-colored info__content info__content-creator">
  <a href="createorpage.html">Creator Name</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId'); //Give your anchor tag an Id or select it however you want and store it in a variable.

```
 if(!creatorUrl){
    a.href = '#';
    }
  else{
  a.href = "somelink url"
 }
```

Comment: OP wants to not have a link at all if there is no href

Comment: that is assuming that I am all about the rep. I have 100K+ so no that is not it. I come from somewhere and attempt to encourage people to read and answer the question. Do not feel discouraged. Just try harder. If you fix your answer I will remove the downvote, if you improve the answer enough I wil even vote it up. At least use a ternary

Comment: Your answer COULD have been `a.href = creatorUrl ? creatorUrl : "#"` which would have been marginally better than what you did answer which is not at all what OP asked